# Parent activity type for NativeActivity activities

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4

Is there any way in which it can be seen the type of the parent activity of a NativeActivity from the [Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781091.aspx) method ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to know this in the execute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can execute the following code block and it will return you the value of the internal `Parent` property -- this will be the instance of your parent.

```
this.GetType()
    .GetProperty(
        "Parent", 
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
    .GetValue(this, null)
```

Comment: oh! Thank you! I've been doing all sorts of hacky stuff to get at the parent's properties. This is much cleaner!