# Get the type/name of the current workflow from within an activity

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I'm new to WF but i've created a custom activity and i'd like to get the name / type of the current workflow.  I've used context.WorkflowInstanceId to get the guid of the current work flow but i'd like to know the name as well i.e. "Workflow1".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workflows don't really have a name.  They may come from a file that has a name or a nameless stream.  You may want to establish your own "name" for the workflow perhaps by passing an argument etc.

Comment: Quick question. Could you not markup the XAML with the x:Name attribute and possibly pull that off through reflection? I haven't fully baked this thought so it may not make a lot of sense - just off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

@RonJacobs is clearly 100% right here - but in addition to that if you're looking for the type of the workflow the activity is residing in (e.g. StateMachine vs. FlowChart) then you can refer to this post I answered recently.  It uses private reflection to get the Parent and then pull the Type off of that.

[Parent activity type for NativeActivity activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882680/parent-activity-type-for-nativeactivity-activities/9299467#9299467)